# When to use "to finishing" and when to use "to finish"?

Tags: gerunds, infinitive-vs-gerund

Which one is correct and why?

"We have to work around the clock to **finish** this video".

"We have to work around the clock to **finishing** this video".

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: "to finishing" is wrong.

Slightly longer answer: the [gerund](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gerund) "finishing" (without "to") is roughly equivalent to the [infinitive](http://www.ef.edu/english-resources/english-grammar/infinitive/) "to finish", and they can be used more-or-less interchangeably. So these two sentences would both be correct:

"We have to work around the clock to finish this video".

"We have to work around the clock, finishing this video".